# How to make a page extend full screen

Tags: themes, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my wordpress theme has invisible margins on both sides of the page, forcing all my content into the middle.

[Example](http://americanpilot.net/sunglasses/).

Comment: There are lots of great Bootstrap tutorials on YouTube. **Know your tools!**

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Warren. Since this is more CSS/Bootstrap related than Wordpress, you might find it better to ask your question at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand the bootstrap framework at all? Your theme has implemented a column width that is smaller than you would probably like.

Your content area is wrapped in an offset column that is 50% of the container width.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

If you want to increase the width of your container you'll need to change the class declaration on that div and remove the offset. The following will make the container 100% of the container width with no offset.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
```

Its possible that your theme has options to affect this. I would be looking there first.

Comment: I am not familiar with bootstrap framework at all, but I appreciate your help. I went into the css and changed col-lg-6's width to 100% but it didn't change anything. Should I wrap the content with <div class="col-sm-1"> (content) </div> ?

Comment: You need to override the margins on each side. In bootstrap you have columns which are contained in a container which is 1170px wide with 15px padding on left and right so you only have 1140px wide container. Your container also has margins which are set to auto inorder to center it. If you want to experiment you can use container-fluid instead of container. Here is a good starting point of learning the bootstrap grid http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @Warren changing the CSS and changing the class for the div are not the same thing. You should try what was suggested in this answer. Replace the `class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3"` with `class="col-sm-12"`